# Foreach PHP only one data appear when echo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$selectra_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_selectra` WHERE user_id='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $selectra_result )) { 
     $product_id = $row['product_id']; 
     $namep[] = $product_name= $row['product_name'];
     $linkp[] = $product_permalink = $row['product_permalink'];
     $imgpp[] = $product_image_path = $row['product_image_path'];    
}

     foreach($namep as $pname => $prodname){
        foreach($linkp as $plink => $prodlink) {
         foreach($imgpp as $ppath => $prodpath) {

        $res1 = "<a href='$prodlink'><p>$prodname</p></a>";
        $res2 = "<a href='$prodlink'><img src='$prodpath'/>";

            }
        }     
      }
      echo $res2.''.$res1;

}
```

I want to display data from my_selectra table using foreach, unfortunately it appears only one data when echo.

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this...

Comment: Is there a flag for `OH DEAR GOD MY EYES`?

Comment: I have a feeling there should be one `foreach`, not three.

Comment: I think what the people are trying to say is: maybe you should start with some basics of programming first because this type of coding is just going to throttle an application, litter the code space, and above all else, not function properly.

Comment: @DampeS8N and Polynomial http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette. There are much nicer ways of communicating your dissatisfaction with OP's example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is pretty convoluted... You don't need 3 arrays to grab the data you want, nor do you need a triple-nested foreach loop structure. Try something like this:

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $selectra_result)) 
{ 
     $product_id = $row['product_id']; 
     $results[] = array( $row['product_name'], $row['product_permalink'], $row['product_image_path']);
}

$res1 = $res2 = '';
foreach( $results as $row)
{
    $res1 .= "<a href='" . $row[1] . "'><p>" . $row[0] . "</p></a>";
    $res2 .= "<a href='" . $row[1] . "'><img src='" . $row[2] . "'/>";
}
echo $res1 . $res2;
```

Comment: Maybe he saved you this once, but I honestly feel sympathy for your employer. You're way over your head and outside your depth. PLEASE seek a professional mentor!

Answer (score 1):

You keep setting `$res1` and `$res2` with each loop.

I think what you meant to do is `$res1 = $res2 = '';` before the loop, then `$res1 .= '...'; $res2 .= '...';` inside the loop.

Comment: This answer doesn't address all the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your echo is in the wrong scope. Place it directly underneath the $res2 variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of double-declarations and variable shifting. I'm not sure you correctly understand basic programming paradigms. You should probably go back to basics, to be honest.

```
 $selectra_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `my_selectra` WHERE user_id='".intval($user_id)."'") or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $selectra_result )) { 
      $product_id = $row['product_id']; 
      $product_name = $row['product_name'];
      $product_image_path = $row['product_image_path'];
      $product_permalink = $row['product_permalink'];

      echo "<a href='$product_permalink'><p>$product_name</p></a>";
      echo "<a href='$product_permalink'><img src='$product_image_path'/>";
 }
```

This is closer to what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Your query most probably selects only one row from the database (if the id column is unique).

And why a loop (foreach) for each array? Considering that all arrays are created (although this is not very clear, because you don't define the variables in the code provided) in the same loop (while) there is no need to do that...